# How to run 3 programs side-by-side with a shell script?

Tags: tmux

I've never used `tmux` before, but as I understand it, I can use it to create panes and run programs side-by-side. Here's what I've got:

```
tmux new-session -d -s busman

tmux split-window -h -p 66 -t busman
tmux split-window -h -p 50 -t busman

tmux attach -t busman
```

When I run this it creates the 3 panes for me. Now how do I start programs in each of them?

Specifically, I want to run `php artisan serve --host 192.168.33.10 --port 80` in the first one, `gulp` in the second, and `cd /vagrant` in the third.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got it:

```
tmux new-session -d -s busman

tmux split-window -h -p 66 -t busman
tmux split-window -h -p 50 -t busman

tmux send-keys -t 0 "sudo php artisan serve --host 192.168.33.10 --port 80"
tmux send-keys -t 1 "gulp"
tmux select-pane -t 2

tmux attach -t busman
```

I don't know why so many tutorials online say you need to put `C-m` at the end. That just causes problems.

**Edit:**

`tmux select-pane -t 2` doesn't actually work from the shell. And I can't get `tmux select-layout even-horizontal` to work either.